# How to hide query string from url using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the link for editing a form :

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."update?z=$zone_id" ?>" >Edit</a>
```

Now in update.php page the url is something like bellow :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/update?z=55
```

Now I want to url should like like bellow :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/update/55
```

How can I do this using .htaccess ?

**Note:** Using current .htaccess rule I am hiding just `.php` extension from the url

**My Current .htaccess file**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([0-9]+) aponit/dev/update.php?z=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Change your link:

```
<a href="http://localhost/aponit/dev/update/<?php echo $zone_id ?>" >Edit</a>
```

Update your `.htaccess` with code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([0-9]+) aponit/dev/update.php?z=$1 [L]
```

Hope helpful for you :)

**Updated .htaccess :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([0-9]+) aponit/dev/update.php?z=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Then should I change the link to like this : update/$zone_id ?

Comment: No, url should be : http://localhost/aponit/dev/update/55, So for that should I change my existing editing link code FROM <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."update?z=$zone_id" ?>" >Edit</a> TO <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."update/$zone_id" ?>" >Edit</a>

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([0-9]+) aponit/dev/update.php?z=$1 [L]`

Comment: I just add this line : RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([0-9]+) aponit/dev/update.php?z=$1 [L] to my given .htaccess file

Comment: @shibbirahmed `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([0-9]+) aponit/dev/update.php?z=$1 [L]`

Comment: should I remove all my existing .htaccess rules ?

Comment: I updated my question with latest .htaccess rules. Is that correct ?

Comment: Just remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]`. I was test, and it work

Comment: If I remove it. It's showing me Note found error message. .

Comment: check my updated question with .htaccess rules. should I delete this line only : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] ?

Comment: Too less information about your code, with normal php code, my awnswer will working very fine.

Comment: Yes, delete this line : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: If I delete it then not found error message is showing

Comment: Path of `update.php` must is: `www\root\aponit\dev\update.php`

Comment: I did it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule in your `.htaccess`. Before you do, make sure your browser cache has been cleared and the rule is placed at the top of your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aponit/dev/update/([^/]*)$ /aponit/dev/update?z=$1 [L]
```